# php artisan make:migration create_flights_table does not make properly generate migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

[Note: THESE HAPPENS WHEN I UPGRADE FROM LARAVEL 8 TO LARAVEL 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib7US.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to this `return new class extends Migration`